# UIButton @selector not calling the method when clicked

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, selector

Here is my code:

```
- (void)loadView {

  //hard coded array of content for each site

  // CC
  NSMutableArray *allccContent = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  NSString *cc1 = @"House Model";
  NSString *cc2 = @"James Dexter History";

  [allccContent addObject: cc1];
  [cc1 release];

  [allccContent addObject: cc2];
  [cc2 release];

  // FC
  NSMutableArray *allfcContent = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  NSString *fc1 = @"Ghost House";
  NSString *fc2 = @"Franklins Letters";
  NSString *fc3 = @"Franklins Business";

  [allfcContent addObject: fc1];
  [fc1 release];

  [allfcContent addObject: fc2];
  [fc2 release];

  [allfcContent addObject: fc3];
  [fc3 release];

  // PC
  NSMutableArray *allphContent = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  NSString *ph1 = @"Changing Occupancy";
  NSString *ph2 = @"Sketches";
  NSString *ph3 = @"Servant House";
  NSString *ph4 = @"Monument";
  NSString *ph5 = @"Virtual Model";

  [allphContent addObject: ph1];
  [ph1 release];

  [allphContent addObject: ph2];
  [ph2 release];

  [allphContent addObject: ph3];
  [ph3 release];

  [allphContent addObject: ph4];
  [ph4 release];

  [allphContent addObject: ph5];
  [ph5 release];

  // Each content page's view

  //UIView *ccContent = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
  UIView *fcContent = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
  UIView *phContent = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];

  //ccContent.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  fcContent.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  phContent.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

  //[ccContent addSubview:[SiteOneController myNavBar1:@"Constitution Center Content"]];
  [fcContent addSubview:[SiteOneController myNavBar1:@"Franklin Court Content"]];
  [phContent addSubview:[SiteOneController myNavBar1:@"Presidents House Content"]];  

  //allocate the view
  self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];

  //set the view's background color
  self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

  [self.view addSubview:[SiteOneController myNavBar1:@"Sites"]];

  NSMutableArray *sites = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  NSString *one = @"Constution Center";
  NSString *two = @"Franklin Court";
  NSString *three = @"Presidents House";

  [sites addObject: one];
  [one release];

  [sites addObject: two];
  [two release];

  [sites addObject: three];
  [three release];

  NSString *ccName = @"Constitution Center";
  NSString *fcName = @"Franklin Court";

  NSString *element;
  int j = 0;
  for (element in sites)
  {
   UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

   //setframe (where on screen)
   //separation is 15px past the width (45-30)
   button.frame = CGRectMake(a, b + (j*45), c, d);

   [button setTitle:element forState:UIControlStateNormal];

   button.backgroundColor = [SiteOneController myColor1];

   /*- (void) fooFirstInput:(NSString*) first secondInput:(NSString*) second {
    NSLog(@"Logs %@ then %@", first, second);
   }
   - (void) performMethodsViaSelectors {
    [self performSelector:@selector(fooNoInputs)];
    [self performSelector:@selector(fooOneInput:) withObject:@"first"];
    [self performSelector;@selector(fooFirstInput:secondInput:) withObject:@"first" withObject:@"second"];*/

   //UIView *old = self.view;

   if (element == ccName) {
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(showCCView:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    else if (element == fcName) {

    }
    else {

    }

   [self.view addSubview: button];
   j++;
  }

 }

// This method show the content views for each of the sites.
+ (void) showCCView:(id) sender {
 NSLog(@"CC CLICKED");
 //UIView *current = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
 //[current addSubview:[SiteOneController ccContent]];
}
```

Now why isn't the showCCView method getting called when the button is clicked? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
+ (void) showCCView:(id) sender {
    NSLog(@"CC CLICKED");
    //UIView *current = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
    //[current addSubview:[SiteOneController ccContent]];
}
```

Because that's a class method, not an instance method.  Change the `+` to a `-`.